# Meshlab Batch convert .wrl files to .ply files

Tags: meshlab

I want to batch convert 5000 .wrl files into .ply files with Meshlab Server.

The command of Meshlab Server to convert a single file is:

```
meshlabserver.exe -i input.wrl -o output.ply
```

for batch convert, I use the command below:

```
for /r %i in (*.wrl) do meshlabserver.exe -i "%i" -o "%i.ply"
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I edit the command to save the output files in another folder?
2. Now the name of output files is `'%i.ply'`, for example, since `%i` is `'1.wrl'`, the output name is `'1.wrl.ply'`. How can I edit the command to change the name into `'1.ply'`?

Thank you!

BR,
Mandy

Comment: Those are not questions related to meshlab, but to your command-line shell.